# Negate pattern in autocmd

Tags: neovim, regular-expression, autocmd, vimscript-lua, pattern

I have some lua auto command that triggers whenever I open a file that has `*/some_pattern/*` in the path.

```
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ 'BufEnter' }, {
    pattern = vim.fn.expand('~') .. '*/some_pattern/*',
    command="echo 'disable'"
})
```

I'd also like to have a command that triggers for the exact opposite.

```
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ 'BufEnter' }, {
    pattern = oppsotite_of(vim.fn.expand('~') .. '*/some_pattern/*'),
    command="echo 'disable'"
})
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise may be could accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your pattern is `*.py` I would do: `{*}{*.py}\@<!`

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ 'BufEnter' }, {
    pattern = '{*}' .. '{' .. '*/some_pattern/*' .. '}\@<!',
    command="echo 'disable'"
})
```

Where:

- `{*}` is the equivalent of `\(.*\)`
- `{*.py}\@<!` is the equivalent of `\(.*\.py\)\@<!`

More information with:

- `:help file-pattern`
- `:help /\@<!`